# How to determine and visualize a representative XGBoost decision tree?

Tags: python, xgboost, decision-tree, graph-visualization, dtreeviz

[dtreeviz](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz) has an easy and a rather intuitive way to visualize decision trees. When we train using a XGBoost model, there are usually many trees created. And the prediction of the test data would involve a cumulative addition of values of all trees to derive the test target values. How do we go about visualising a representative tree from those trees?

In my attempt to answer this question, I used sklearn California Housing data and trained with XGBoost. Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import xgboost as xgb

housing = fetch_california_housing()
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(housing.data, housing.target, 
                                                   test_size = 0.33, random_state = 11)
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(data=X_train, label=y_train)
dvalid= xgb.DMatrix(data=X_valid, label=y_valid)

# specify xgboost parameters and train the model
params_reg = {"max_depth":4, "eta":0.3, "objective":"reg:squarederror", "subsample":1}
xgb_model_reg = xgb.train(params=params_reg, dtrain=dtrain, num_boost_round=1000, \
      early_stopping_rounds=50, evals=[(dtrain, "train"),(dvalid, "valid")], verbose_eval=True)
```

As I used `early_stopping_rounds`, it stopped at the following iteration:

```
[0] train-rmse:1.46031  valid-rmse:1.47189
[1] train-rmse:1.14333  valid-rmse:1.15873
[2] train-rmse:0.93840  valid-rmse:0.95947
[3] train-rmse:0.80224  valid-rmse:0.82699
...
[308]   train-rmse:0.28237  valid-rmse:0.47431
[309]   train-rmse:0.28231  valid-rmse:0.47429
```

`xgb_model_reg.best_iteration` was 260.

Using this best tree, I plotted a dtreeviz tree as follows:

```
from dtreeviz import trees
from dtreeviz.models.xgb_decision_tree import ShadowXGBDTree

best_tree = xgb_model_reg.best_iteration
xgb_shadow_reg = ShadowXGBDTree(xgb_model_reg, best_tree, housing.data, housing.target, \
                                housing.feature_names, housing.target_names)
trees.dtreeviz(xgb_shadow_reg)
```

We get this visual:
[image: XGBoost best_iteration tree]

If I were to use this `ShadowXGBDTree` to draw the prediction path through this tree for a validation row, it returns a different value that what the model predicts. For illustration, I randomly chose `X_valid[50]` and plotted its prediction path, as follows:

```
# predict
y_pred = xgb_model_reg.predict(dvalid)
# select a sample row and visualize path
X_sample = X_valid[50]
viz = trees.dtreeviz(xgb_shadow_reg,
                    X_valid, 
                    y_valid, 
                    target_name='MedHouseVal', 
                    orientation ='LR',  # left-right orientation
                    feature_names=housing.feature_names,
                    class_names=list(housing.target_names),
                    X=X_sample)            
viz
```

The predicted target value is 2.13 as shown:
[image: Decision Tree prediction path]

However, `y_valid[50]` is 1.741 and even `y_pred[50]` is 1.5196749, where neither match the value shown in the diagram. I guess this is expected, as I am only using this specific tree for path prediction. How should I select a representative tree, then?

Any thoughts how best to approach this issue? Thank you.

Comment: I did the same question here: [how can I get the final tree model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72311192/how-can-i-get-the-final-tree-model) If you have found an answer please let me know!

Comment: Any luck with this?  Only thing I can think is that the order of features got messed up and swapped somehow.

Comment: @Chris/Kevin, I decided to pursue a different path to help with explaining a model prediction.

Answer (score 3):

After exploring this question for some months, I decided to respond with the direction I have chosen to move forth as others seem to be in a similar situation. My primary aim with this question was to figure out if there is a way to explain a prediction from the XGBoost model. Due to the way XGBoost is theoretically defined, however, it does not look feasible to obtain a single representative decision tree. Instead, I decided to perform [SHAP analysis](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to explain its prediction.

Continuing on with the code given in the question, here is the gist of the code to perform SHAP analysis:

```
import shap

# Create a tree explainer
xgb_explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(
    xgb_model_reg, X_train, feature_names=list(housing.feature_names)
)
data_dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(data=X_valid,label=y_valid)
y_pred = xgb_model_reg.predict(data_dmatrix)

shap_explainer_values = xgb_explainer(X_valid, y_pred)
```

For illustration, if we want to explain why y_pred[50] had 1.5196749, for example, we could generate a waterfall plot with this line:

```
shap.waterfall_plot(shap_explainer_values[50])
```

Here is the resulting waterfall plot:

[image]

From this plot, features longitude and latitude had the biggest effect on this prediction in opposite directions. The house's latitude positively increased by 2 from the batch base value `E[f(x)]`, however its longitude brought down the value by -2.19. Such a representation readily helps to explain a model prediction.

Answer (score 0):

In the "[dtreeviz](https://explained.ai/decision-tree-viz/index.html)" library, the approach is to identify the most important decision trees within the ensemble of trees in the XGBOOST model. They expect you to provide the most crucial tree (a single decision tree), which is defined as the "[best_tree](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.Booster.best_iteration)" variable in our example above. So, while this method of visualization is not the worst, we must remember that there are hundreds of other trees influencing our decisions.

Shapley values are among the most common methods for interpreting the influence of inputs on a machine learning model, either for a specific sample or across the entire dataset. However, it's a general model, which means it's not tailored solely for decision tree models. It offers a more robust way to understand the contribution of each data point in complex models, but it only gives us a broad overview.